# spring integration tcp server shutdown

Tags: java, tcp, server, spring-integration, shutdown

I have written tcp server using spring integration. Thanks to excellent sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server
Sample server stops if the user pressed q on the console.

TCP Server is a stand alone application and runs perfectly fine accepting requests and sending responses. I would like to add orderly shutdown of the server because Console access is not possible if the server is started as a background process.

is there a way for the server to wait for events? If the shutdown event comes then I can call applicationContext.stop().

I would appreciate if you can suggest any ideas on orderly shutdown process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of "event" you are talking about but there are a number of things you can do.

If you enable JMX, the `IntegrationMBeanExporter` provides for [orderly shutdown](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-mbean-shutdown).

In the case of TCP, this stops it from accepting new connections, drops any new requests and gives you time to wait for any in-process requests to terminate).

You can use a [control-bus](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus) to send a stop request to the inbound endpoint.

The source for the control bus message could be anything you want - another tcp adapter...

```
telnet 123.123.123.123
bar.stop()
```

or using any other messaging technology.

Or you could just use the OS to kill the JVM.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. That is what I am looking for.